# Working with Amazon Web Services

Tags: amazon-web-services, communication, instance

I have to build an online bookstore using AWS using SQS, SES and RDS services as homework but Im at a standstill. I read through the documentations about these services provided by Amazon but I cannot figure out how to make them communicate with each other and how to set up instances with the named services. SQS should be the backbone of this store. RDS should contain users and products in stock and SES is used to notification for the customer. I search google as thoroughly as I could but could not find anything related to my problem. If anyone could give me some pointers or lead me to some reading I may have missed I would be most grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These services talk to each other, but they are functionally separate.  You connect to and populate an RDS database the same way you'd connect to and populate any remote MySQL database.  SQS and SES both are driven through the AWS API, which you tap into using the Amazon API tools:

http://aws.amazon.com/developertools?_encoding=UTF8&jiveRedirect=1

You just create your Amazon AWS account, get your access credentials, put them into the environment variables (read the READMEs in the tools downloads) and start using them.

hope that helps.

Comment: I made the AWS account (currently waiting for confirmation mail) and have set up AWS toolkit for Eclipse. I worked through services individually by studying the Java example codes. That part I understand (sort of). What I can't figure out is how to run the services on instances (should I just install Java on the instance and run the application?) and how to make the queue to speak with email service. It's all new for me, sorry for any silly questions :).

Comment: Everyone learns at some point.  :)  The ec2 instances are your glue to the other services.  The queue doesn't speak to the email service.  The business logic (ie. code) on your ec2 instance puts stuff up onto the queue, pulls stuff from the queue, sends requests to the email service, etc.  So, your Java code would serve as that glue.  You'll create logic like "when a book order comes in, thank the customer and put it into a queue", and separately "when there are items in the queue, build an order and then post a notification to SNS", etc.  Hope that helps.

Comment: Your help is much appreciated, Rob :). So basically I create the queues I need, the database instance and write the code to use them (work with SES according to messages in the queue and so on)? For example, with the queues, they are always there and I can connect to them and get messages from them using the QueueUrl. Thanks again for your help Rob :).